# Save Item from Jlist

Tags: java, string, swing, actionlistener, jlist

I have a `JList` that is populated from database.
My idea is , when i click in one item from `JList`, that selection is saved on a `String`.

```
final JList list = new JList();
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
list.setBounds(24, 107, 256, 407);
getContentPane().add(list);
```

How I can save in `String`, a item selected from `JList`? need to do any `ActionListener`?

Comment: `list.setBounds(24, 107, 256, 407);`   Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  For a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or combinations of them, along with layout padding & borders for white space, to organize the components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to implement a

```
ListSelectionListener
```

and in the method

```
valueChanged(...)
```

you can store the value of the selected String by using

```
String value = list.getSelectedValue();
```

or if you have selected more you can use a String array as

```
String[] values = list.getSelectedValues();
```

Comment: Beware that this is only going to work in Java 7 (which means getSelectedValues is deprecated) and assumes that the OP has setup the JList to use generics, which from there example they haven't. getSelectedValue/s will, otherwise return an Object/Object array

Comment: @MadProgrammer so what is the new way in Java 8 ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild With out reading the APIs, I'd say it'll work similar to Java 7 ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer backward compatibility ? ;)

Comment: Well, technically, JList is the the same as JList<Object> so unless you are specially compiling using Java 7/8 it should work ;)